# Passing multiple objects in phalcon form

Tags: php, phalcon

I have a from that have fields from another model. some of them are many-to-many and some one-to-one Problem is when i try to edit form i can only pass 1 object like

```
$this->view->form = new CourseForm($course, array(
        'edit' => true
    ));
```

Here i also want to pass $course->location because location is different model and relationship is one 2 one. when i pass

```
$this->view->form = new CourseForm($course->location, array(
        'edit' => true
    ));
```

Only location show up in view.

So is there any way to pass multiple objects in Form. I dont want to create a new form for each model.

So in a nutshell how can i do this

```
$this->view->form = new CourseForm($course + $course->location, array(
            'edit' => true
        ));
```

Comment: Why to put `$course + $course->location` if your $course object already contains location property and you can access it in the CourseForm constructor via $course variable?

Comment: in the view i am using $form->render. It render only info related to course not $course->location. but i found a way out. since i am new to phalcon.

Comment: Perhaps you should answer your own question or update your question with the answer if you don't have enough rep yet. That way other people who have the same problem can see the solution

Answer (score 0):

I've just split the course into

```
$this->view->form = new CourseForm($course , array(
        'edit' => true
    ));
```

And

```
$this->view->location = new CourseForm( $course->location, array(
        'edit' => true
    ));
```

> And in the view i've just changed $form->render to $location->render